# SQL - Display columns from two tables with where clause, preform count and GROUP BY COLUMNS in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One table is the main  registered Boat table that holds most of the information. it has many columns one of them is [MFR CODE].

The other table is a reference table that contains all the records associated with only Business Boats and it has only 3 columns : [MFR CODE], [MFR NAME] & [MODEL]

I'm trying to find how many times (count) Business Boats appear in the Registered boat tables.

```
 SELECT 
  Count(*) As 'TotalNumberBoats'
  , [BoatsReg].[dbo].[MASTER].[MFR MDL CODE]
  ,[BoatsReg].[dbo].[BusinessBoats].[MFR]
  ,[BoatsReg].[dbo].[BusinessBoats].[MODEL]
 FROM [BoatsReg].[dbo].[MASTER],[BoatsReg].[dbo].[BusinessBoats]
 Where [BoatsReg].[dbo].[MASTER].[MFR MDL CODE] =  [BoatsReg].[dbo].[BusinessBoats].[CODE]
  group by [BoatsReg].[dbo].[BusinessBoats].[CODE]    
  order by TotalNumberBoats asc
```

1. How do i get rid of all the square brackets, it's annoying.
2. why do i get an error ?

Comment: first  you don't it delimiters the column and table names, if you don't have spaces or restricted words, you don't need them, but for all pruposes, use them. whta error?

Comment: If the connection is currently using the `BoatsReg` database then you can remove all of the `[BoatsReg]` references. Comma joins, i.e.: `FROM table1, table2`, haven't really been a thing since SQL-92 was a thing - you should be using `JOIN` syntax, e.g.: `FROM dbo.MASTER m JOIN dbo.BusinessBoats bb ON m.[MFR MDL CODE] = bb.CODE`. As just seen the `[]` aren't necessary unless an object name conflicts with an SQL keyword, contains whitespace, etc..

Comment: Also, it's frowned upon to use string literals for column names, `Count(*) As 'TotalNumberBoats'`, this is somewhere you'd actually use square brackets, `Count(*) As [TotalNumberBoats]`

Comment: The error I'm getting is
Column 'BoatsReg.dbo.BusinessBoats.MFR' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You get rid of the square brackets by getting rid of them. Just delete them, they are not necessary unless you have weird naming. Also, comma-joins are deprecated and should be avoided, use normal `FROM Table1 AS SomAlias JOIN Table2 AS Alias2 ON ...`

Comment: As for removing the brackets from auto-generated code, I can offer two approaches, both of which should be proof-read before use: (1) If you know all of your identifiers contain no special characters or keywords, just search and replace all brackets. (2) Use the regular-expression mode or your search and replace dialog and replace all `\[(\w+)\]` with `$1`. You may have to selectively re-quote certain identifiers like `order` or `count`. A final word of caution: Don't do this is the original SQL or the schema from which it was generated came from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you aggregate a result, you have to specify all other fixed columns in the GROUP BY clause

(Answer edited to add total row with a UNION ALL and add a sort field to put the total row as last one)

In your case:

```
 SELECT 1 as sorted,
  ,Count(*) As TotalNumberBoats
  ,MASTER.[MFR MDL CODE]
  ,BusinessBoats.MFR
  ,BusinessBoats.MODEL
 FROM BoatsReg, BusinessBoats
 Where MASTER.[MFR MDL CODE] = BusinessBoats.CODE
 Group by
  ,MASTER.[MFR MDL CODE]
  ,BusinessBoats.MFR
  ,BusinessBoats.MODEL 

 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 as sorted,
  ,Count(*) As TotalNumberBoats
  ,'','',''
 FROM BoatsReg

 Order by sorted, TotalNumberBoats
```

Comment: 1. Thank you much.
2. How do i present a sum of TotalNumberBoats at the last row of the table ?
i can get the sum with rollup but how do i position it at the last row ?

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it helped you. I'll think about your last question